# Vim -- how to control formatoptions when opening up a file with no filetype?

Tags: vim

i have my `formatoptions` set like this in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
set formatoptions=caq1njw
```

Sometimes I run a script which lets me edit a temporary plain-text file which has paths that begin with `//` (They are perforce file paths).

This causes vim to apply wrapping comment paragraph rules so if I have a few short file paths that add up to less than `textwidth` characters long, it will merge the file paths while I edit this file list! This would be super extra bad.

Now I know how to get Vim to apply different settings upon opening different filetypes by using the `.vim/after/ftplugin`. For instance if I wanted `formatoptions` to be something specific for javascript files I would edit some `ftplugin/javascript.vim` file, as evidenced by this:

```
:verbose set formatoptions
  formatoptions=a1njwcroql
        Last set from ~/bin/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/javascript.vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

(my vim is installed under `~/bin`, yeah, this is unconventional)

So it looks like the bundled javascript.vim is applying `l` and `r` in addition to my `.vimrc`'s `caq1njw`. That's fine, I can configure vim's behavior for javascript however I want.

But what I want is for plain, normal, undetected filetype files to NOT use `caq1njw`. And, for all other recognized filetypes to use `caq1njw`.

Is there a way to do this without adding `set formatoptions=caq1njw` to each and every filetype that I use?

Basically some sort of `ftplugin/vanilla.vim` that is run only when the filetype is undetected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that temporary plain-text file follows any (path and/or filename) pattern, I'd define an autocmd on that:

```
:autocmd BufNew,BufRead /tmp/tempfile*.tmp setlocal formatoptions=...
```

For the general case, it's difficult to trigger on the `FileType` event **not** being thrown. You'd have to use another event that comes *after* that, e.g.:

```
:autocmd BufWinEnter * if empty(&l:filetype) | setlocal formatoptions=... | endif
```

I'd go with the first alternative, though.